# Best practice for using NotifierProvider with a textField or dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have been converting my app from global variables to riverpod 2.0 NotifierProviders.

I am wondering how I should handle a dropdownbutton?

Here is the original code:

```
return DropdownButton<String>(
                                    hint: const Text("Select Agent"),
                                    value: _currentAgent,
                                    onChanged: changedDropDownAgent,  <<< CALL FUNCTION
                                    items: snapshot.data.docs
                                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((document) {
                                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                        value: document.id,
                                        child: Text(
                                            '${document.data()['fName']} ${document.data()['lName']}'),
                                      );
                                    }).toList(),
                                  );
```

Here is the change function code:

```
void changedDropDownAgent(String? selectedUser) {
    setState(() {
      _currentUser = selectedUser;
    });
    globals.selectedUser = selectedUser;
  }
```

My question:
Can I do away with the changedDropDownAgent function and replace it with a ref.watch(NotifierProvider) ?

Here is what I am talking about:

```
return DropdownButton<String>(
                                    hint: const Text("Select Agent"),
                                    value: _currentAgent,
                                    onChanged: ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserName; 
                                    items: snapshot.data.docs
                                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((document) {
                                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                        value: document.id,
                                        child: Text(
                                            '${document.data()['fName']} ${document.data()['lName']}'),
                                      );
                                    }).toList(),
                                  );
```

If I do this I think I can do away with the changedDropDownAgent because the NotifierProvider will be taking care of state.

Does my logic make sense?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of `globalsNotifierProvider`?

Comment: Your onChanged: needs to be a closure that *updates* the globals.  It'll be closer to something like onChanged: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updateCurrentUserName, where updateCurrentUsername takes an incoming value and replaces the existing value with it.